The inverse image functor induced from morphism of ringed spaces commutes with the image?
Let $ f: (X, \mathcal{O}_X)  \to  (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a morphism of ringed spaces and let $ w : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'$ be a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules.
Then
Q. $f^*(\operatorname{im} w) \cong \operatorname{im}(f^* w)$ ?
I am trying to show this by noting that $f^*$ admits a right adjoint functor ( $f_*$) so that $f^*$  commutes with inductive limits but I'm not sure about that $\operatorname{im}$ is a kind of inductive limits. My first trial is as follows : Since the category of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules form an abelian category, $\operatorname{im} w = \operatorname{coim} w$. So, since the cokernel is an inductive limit, by letting $i : \ker(w) \rightarrowtail \mathcal{F}$ be the induced morphism from $w:\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'$,
$$ f^{*}(\operatorname{im} w) = f^{*}( \operatorname{coim} w ) := f^{*}( \operatorname{Coker} ( i : \ker(w) \rightarrowtail \mathcal{F})) = \operatorname{Coker}( f^{*}(i) :  f^{*}(\ker w) \to f^{*}\mathcal{F}) \\ \stackrel{?}{=} \operatorname{Coker}(  j : \ker (f^* w) \rightarrowtail f^* \mathcal{F} ) =: \operatorname{coim}(f^* w) = \operatorname{im}(f^* w),$$
where the $j : \ker (f^* w) \rightarrowtail f^* \mathcal{F}$ is the induced morphism from $f^{*} w : f^{*} \mathcal{F} \to f^{*} \mathcal{F}'$. But I am not sure whether the equality marked by question mark is true.. First of all, $f^{*}(\ker w) = \ker (f^* w)$? $f^*$ also commutes with finite limit? Am I missing something? If in general not, when the question is possible? ( e.g. $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}'$ are quasi-coherent.. )

sorry, I retract my answer because there is an extremely annoying distinction between $f^{-1}$ - the sheaf pullback I'm used to - and $f^\ast$ - the pullback which lands in $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules that geometers use - and while $f^{-1}$ is definitely exact, I'm not so sure about $f^\ast$.

O.K. I recognized it..

you might have to assume $f$ is a flat morphism of locally ringed spaces, I think

O.K. I will try to it ! :)

I don't think this is true. Indeed, take a ring $A$ and an ideal $I \subseteq A$ with $w$ the inclusion map. Then if $f^\sharp:A \rightarrow B= A/I$ is not flat (with $f$ the induced map $f: \mathrm{Spec}(B) \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(A)$), it need not be the case that $f^*(\mathrm{im}(\tilde{w})) = \widetilde{I \otimes_A B}$ is the same as $\mathrm{im}(f^* \tilde{w}) = \widetilde{\mathrm{im}(w\otimes B)}$.
For example, if we take $A = \mathbb{C}[x]$, with $I$ the ideal generated by $x$ and $B = \mathbb{C}[x]/(x)$ (so $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, $Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$, the $f$ is the inclusion of the origin, and $\mathcal{F} = \widetilde{I}$ and $\mathcal{F'} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])}$), then $\mathrm{im}( w) \cong \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_Y$ so $f^*(\mathrm{im}( w)) = \mathcal{O}_X$, but $f^*w = 0$ (i.e. is the zero map).
I also think you have it the other way round: BEING a right adjoint means you commute with limits, not admitting a right adjoint. So in this case, $f^*$ commutes with colimits, not limits.
I don't know of a general condition for when pullback commutes with images, but I think it basically boils down to some kind of flatness - indeed if we assume $w$ is injective (eg replacing $\mathcal{F}$ with $\mathcal{F}/\mathrm{ker}(w)$), we're basically asking if $f^*(w)$ is injective.

Thank you. Can I ask more? In your counter(?) example, why $\mathcal{F}:=\tilde{I}  =\mathcal{O}_Y$ and why $f^(w) : f^{} ( \tilde{I}) = (\widetilde{ B \otimes_A I}) \to  f^{*}(\tilde{A})=(\widetilde{B\otimes_A A})=\tilde{B} =\mathcal{O}_X$ is the zero map?

And in the first paragraph in your answer, I don't understand what the notation $ \operatorname{im}(w \otimes f^{\sharp})$ exactly means.

So on the level of rings, this is just the statement that $I = (x)$ is a free module of rank 1 (indeed,  multiplication by $x$ is an $A$-linear isomorphism $A \xrightarrow{\sim} I$). Now if you tensor the inclusion map $I \rightarrow A$ (if we identify $I$ with $A$ via the isomorphism I just described then this is just multiplication by $x$ going from $A \rightarrow A$) with $B$ (note $f^*$ is just tensoring with $B$ and applying $\sim$), then the map is multiplication by $x$ from $B$ to $B$. But $x=0$ in $B$.

and sorry, I should have written $w \otimes B$: we are just applying the functor $(-)\otimes_A B$ to $w$.

O.K. I got it. Thanks for kind explanation !~
